# Getting context of an app launched by a launcher

Tags: android, android-context

I have a launcher application with a populated gridView of installed apps. I use the following code to launch an app that has been selected:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        OurAppInfo info = (OurAppInfo) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
        Intent intent = Constants.mPackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageInfo.packageName);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        startActivity(intent);
        });
```

Is there a way to get the context of the activity that is being launched using the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because that application is in another process with another Dalvik VM instance, not yours.